# Can Oozie "ok to" tag be parameterized?

Tags: oozie, oozie-workflow

I have a use case where parent-workflow.xml calls sub-workflow.xml, where I will be passing parameters to sub-workflow.xml through multiple actions of the parent-workflow. 
Can I access a property/parameter at one of the "ok to" tag of sub-workflow's action.

Parent-action:

```
<action name="step3">
    <sub-workflow>
        <app-path>${sub_workflow_path_el}</app-path>
        <propagate-configuration />
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>job_tracker</name>
                <value>${job_tracker}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>name_node</name>
                <value>${name_node}</value>
            </property>
            <property>
                <name>is_audit_required</name>
                <value>N</value> 
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </sub-workflow>
    <ok to="step4"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Sub-workflow-action:

```
<action name="Hive_job" cred="hive-beeline">
    <hive2 xmlns="uri:oozie:hive2-action:0.1">
        <param>lastUpdateDate=${lastUpdateDate}</param>
        <argument>hive.execution.engine=spark</argument>
    </hive2>
    <ok to="audit_${is_audit_required}" />
    <error to="email_notification" />
</action>
```

Basing on the flag, I will be calling the respective actions of workflow.

with the above getting an error:

OozieClientException: org.apache.oozie.DagEngineException: E0701: XML schema error, cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'audit_${is_audit_required}' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern '(a-zA-Z_*){1,39}' for type 'IDENTIFIER'.

Please help.

Comment: Not like that -- DAG definition is static. But you can branch to a **decision** action i.e. _"if  ${x} = 'a' then goto ACTION_A else if ..."_ >> that's not the actual EL syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: Cf. tutorial http://hadooped.blogspot.com/2013/07/apache-oozie-part-9a-coordinator-jobs.html under "decision control"